# How do I serialize when Writer subclass of iobase.write writes records into server local and the Writer process works on multiple workers?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

The Document of "Custom Sources and Sinks (Python)" (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io-python) 
describes that the writing process works with multiple workers.

How can the "finalize_write" of the custom Sink handles workers storage when Pipeline I/O uses server local storage?

I am writing the custom Sink which support .gz writing. It requires to use local hard disk for text output.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

finalize_write is useful for performing additional external actions after the data bundles have been processed, such as renaming files on GCS.  For your sink to work, it needs to have exported the data out of the Dataflow pipeline via the Writer; it can buffer the data temporarily to local disk if it needs to, but the data can't remain there past the end of the bundle.